# Does anyone know any reference for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

For $n \geq 4$, $A$ is $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ tridiagonal block matrix
$$A = n^2 \begin{bmatrix}B & -I & 0 & \cdots & \\-I & B & -I & 0 & 
\\ 0  & -I & B & -I & \cdots 
\\ \cdots  & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots
\\ \cdots  & \cdots & -I & B & -I
\\ \cdots  & \cdots & 0 & -I & B \end{bmatrix}$$

where $B$ is again $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ tridiagonal matrix

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}4 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & \\-1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & 
\\ 0  & -1 & 4 & -1 & \cdots 
\\ \cdots  & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots
\\ \cdots  & \cdots & -1 & 4 & -1
\\ \cdots  & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

(Hence the size of $A$ is $(n-1)^2 \times (n-1)^2$)

The eigenvalues of $A$ are given by $4n^2 (\sin^2(\mu \pi /(2n)) + \sin^2(\nu \pi /(2n)))$ for $\mu, \nu = 1, 2, \cdots, n-1$.

My professor gave a problem computing the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$ using numerical analysis, and I have to compare it to the exact closed form of eigenvectors which my professor gave.

However, using Matlab, I checked that my professor's exact closed form is wrong (multiplying $A$ to that vector $v$ does not give some kind of $kv$ - I guess maybe there was some typo in his paper).

So, does anyone know any reference about the closed form of eigenvectors of this matrix? Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you weren't aware of this before, this seems to be the matrix involved in the five-point stencil method to discretize the Poisson equation... perhaps you could look for references on that. (A Google search seems to turn up a couple references, I lack the time to search them through in detail for applicability right now).

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Pure_Dirichlet_boundary_conditions_2

Comment: This matrix is the first example in Chapter 6 of Miroslav Fiedler's _Special Matrices and Their Applications in Numerical Mathematics_.